# get fieldname of a data struct matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have the following nested struct:

hole 1x200 struct, diam 1x12 struct, which has the following fields: pos, freq1, fre12

That is:

```
hole(1 to 200).diam(1 to 12).pos
                            .freq1
                            .freq2
```

From a value (`freq1` and `freq2`), I would like to obtain the field name of the struct. So I will need to find the value that matches with freq1 and freq2 and show the fieldname.

I tried to use structfun in order to apply a function to each field.

```
[struct.field]=structfun(@(x) find(x.freq1==27.059783995484867 & freq2==76.468355874897000))
```

But I guess I am writing something wrong on the code.

Also I create an anonymous fuction but I have the following error:

> 'Error using structfun / Inputs to STRUCTFUN must be scalar
>   structures'

. How ever when I verified if  an specific value of the struct is scalar, I have a positive answerd: `isscalar(hole(130).diam(10))`

I belive I more near the solution using this script:

```
myfun=@(yourarray,desiredvalue) yourarray==desiredvalue;
%//Apply function to each field of scalar structure, it SCALAR??
desiredfieldindex=myfun(structfun(@(x) x,hole),26.697046257785030) 
desiredFieldName=fNames(desiredFieldIndex)
```

I don´t know if I am in the rigth path, or I should utilize the function find. ALso I that case I don´t know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things.

1. **FLOATING POINT VALUES!** Careful!! Never compare a floating point value as `val==0.3`! do `abs(val-0.3)<10^-8` or something similar. [Read more here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).
2. You are using `structfun` wrong. The function needs 2 arguments, and you are just passing 1! However, `structfun` will apply a function to each field so you are not using it rigth either in that sense. Lets see an example

example:

```
a.hithere=5;
a.notthis=3;
fun=@(x)x==5;
[isfive]=structfun(fun,a)


isfive =

     1
     0
```

As you can see, it applies the function to each of them. If you try to change the function to `fun=@(x)x.hithere==5` you will get an error! As the function is applied to each field, and `x.hithere.hithere` or `x.notthis.hithere` do not exist.

If you want to check both values, you will need to check them independently making two separated calls to `structfun` or avoiding `structfun` and just making a for loop.

Comment: I have been trying some examples, and when I implement your logic into my programs, it doesn´t work.                                                                  My situation is the following

Comment: @NicolasT. "it doesnt work"? Why it doesn't work? because for the question asked, works.

Comment: I apologized @Ander, I was wrinting and I submit the comment, by mistake. My example is the following:                                                     hole(1).diam(1).pos=1; hole(1).diam(1).freq1=3;hole(1).diam(1).freq2=2;
hole(2).diam(1).pos=2;hole(2).diam(1).freq1=4;hole(2).diam(1).freq2=5;y=struct2table(hole) %I would like to obtain the field from a freq1. In other words, find the field that has the same freq1.
%For instance: freq1=3
%y=strcutfun(find(...)...);
y=hole(1).diam(1)  I would like to obtain this as the answerd    I am new here, I don´t know how to edit well the comment

Comment: @NicolasT. I migth not have been clear enough, structfun does not allow you to insert an structure with multiple repeated fields, as `.diam(1);.diam(2)`. You will need to loop.

Comment: Yes, not only am I able to create it, but also I can acces the data.                          hole(1).diam(1).freq1=3;                                                     hole(1).diam(2).freq1=2;                                                     hole(2).diam(1).freq1=7;                                                  hole(2).diam(2).freq1=9;   I would like to find any frequency and obtain its field. For instance:     find(freq1==9)                                           Result: hole(2).diam(2). I hope I could clarify the situation

Comment: Yeah, @NicolasT. you are very clear. Am I not being clear? Write a foor loop, do not use `sructfun`

Comment: Thanks  @AnderBiguri. I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: @NicolasT. No problem. Consider accepting the answer for future reference.